# .NET application directory translation

Tags: c#, .net, directory, translation

I am having this problem that comes up only on French Windows users of my company's software. I suspect it has something to do with directory name translation, although I'm not sure.

I am looking up the application path using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. On English OSs this gives something that includes `C:\Program Files`, which is correct. However, on French systems the application is installed in `C:\Programmes`. Having said that, it seems that there is some sort of realtime translation going on because if you open the folder structure in command prompt, it's still `C:\Program Files`. The `BaseDirectory` call also gives `C:\Program Files` on French systems.

Anyway, it seems that the English path cannot be then used to look for files on French systems, because it's resulting in a `FileNotFoundException`.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you use the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration to specify the `Program Files` directory?

Comment: What if you use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)